# How can I get the project name in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there an easier way to get the project name rather than parsing the path to the execution directory? *JavaSE-1.6*

Comment: What's a "project name" to Java?  That's usually managed by an IDE, and has nothing to do with Java itself.

Comment: how do you define `project name`?

Comment: Are you looking for System.getProperty("user.dir")?

Comment: Java doesn't have anything like a "project". Are you referring to IDE projects (e.g. projects in Eclipse, NetBeans or whatever you're using)?

Comment: in non-static context, you could call `this.getClass().getPackage();` to get the package name. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: For compiled Java, there is no notion of a project. There are classes and packages.

Comment: Ah OK. I'm working with Eclipse. There it's called *project name* and it's the string of the folder which contains the whole application.

Comment: Create instance variable String proName; and implement setters and getters...[sarcasm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making use of a jar archive file for your application and ant builds you can do the following;

1. You can have the ant build file set a value (Project-name) in the MANIFEST.MF file, excample;

```
    <manifest file="${basedir}\resources\jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />
        <attribute name="Version" value="${release.version}" />
        <attribute name="Company" value="S1" />
        <attribute name="Project" value="<project_name>" />
        <attribute name="Java-Version" value="1.5" />
    </manifest>
</target>

<target name="dist_jar" depends="create_manifest">
    <delete file="${basedir}\build\jar\${jar.name}" />

    <!--Create the JAR for the build-->

    <jar jarfile="${basedir}\resources\jar\${jar.name}" 
        manifest="${basedir}\resources\jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF" 
        basedir="${jar.classes}" />
</target>
```

2. Read the Project name from the MANIFEST.MF. See [Read Manifest from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615493/how-do-i-read-the-manifest-file-for-a-webapp-running-in-apache-tomcat).

Comment: Hmmm ... is that the Eclipse project name, or the project name from the Ant build.xml file?

Comment: I just made it project name as an example. The closest thing I got to retrieving the project name from the .project eclipse file is: http://blog.vizio360.co.uk/2009/11/eclipse-get-project-name-within-ant-script/

Comment: Yo can also strip the ${basedir} property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454128/ant-basedir-and-eclipse-project-file-generation

Answer (score 3):

> Ah OK. I'm working with Eclipse. There it's called project name and it's the string of the folder which contains the whole application.

Firstly, this is an IDE-specific concept.  Java (in general) has no concept of a project.

Second, it is probably not a good idea to make a program depend on the name of the Eclipse project.  That will cause problems if you ever try to run your program independently of Eclipse and the build environment.